# Limiting Size of a Data Table C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using a data table to store data. This data table is bound to a data grid view element on my GUI which displays the entries in real time. The number of entries into this data table grows at a fast rate and as it does, my GUI freezes up. How can I limit the number of rows, or entries into this data table? I need it to display at least 100 entries, but it also needs to keep scrolling to display new data. In other words, out with the old, in with the new. I also just don't want to clear the data table when it reaches 100 entries as it would look odd on the GUI when that happens. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you have a threading issue, not a data size issue

Comment: Please, post the code where you're updating the datatable and grid view

Comment: You can easily get the UI thread to burn 100% core, trying to keep up with the constant need to keep the binding updated.  At which point it stops taking care of the lower priority jobs, painting and responding to input.  If buffering the data so you don't poke the grid so often doesn't solve it then binding is the problem and not the solution.  You'll then need to display only a snapshot of the data, stable to give the user's eyes a break as well.

Comment: I can't post any of my code (Security issues with my job). Sorry. It just basically an initial bind to the data table, each time I get data, i append using a delegate, as I am in a separate thread. It may help to note that when I turn the live update  functionality off, the freezing does not persist, as one would suspect. I also have a function that puts focus on the newest row in the DGV. That also may attribute to the freezing?

Comment: What technology are you using? WPF, Winforms...asp.net? Add it as a tag to the post.

Comment: The more and more I test, the more it seems like the problem lies in the datagridview.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex. I set this equal to the datagridview.Rows.Count - 1, each time a new row is added. Possibly the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get new data too frequently you could approach it with 2 ways:

- Create refresh button
- Refresh automatically after X rows have been added or after X seconds.

For both approach you need to do loading to `DataTable` inside separated `Thread` so your UI doesn't freeze and then using one of above methods you just `invoke dgv.DataSource = DataTableFromOtherThread`

Since it is clear how to do it with button and with Timer (after x seconds) i will explain just `after X rows`

For `after X rows` method use [DataTable.TableNewRow event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.tablenewrow?view=netframework-4.7.2) and increas `int currentlyAdded` by 1 each time and `if(currentlyAdded >= 100) { invoke assigning DataTable to datasource }`